# Inconsistent behaviour across compilers in regard to instantiation of a template in a discarded if constexpr(false) statement

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

I am trying to understand whether the snippet below should compile according to The Standard or not. When I try to compile it with latest version of three major compilers, the following occurs:

- **✓** Clang (version 7.0.0, with `-std=c++17` flag): compiles fine;
- **✓** GCC (version 8.2, with `-std=c++17` flag): also compiles fine;
- **❌** MSVC (version 19.16, with `/std:c++17` flag): compiler error (see below).

The error occurs because the MSVC compiler seemingly tries to instantiate `std::optional<void>` despite the fact that the code is discarded. GCC and Clang don't seem to do that.

**Does The Standard clearly define what should occur in this case?**

```
#include <optional>  
#include <type_traits>
template<typename T, typename... Args>
struct Bar
{
  void foo(Args... args)
  {
    if constexpr(!std::is_same_v<T, void>) // false
    {
      // MSVC compiler error occurs because of the line below; no error occurs when compiling with GCC and Clang 
      std::optional<T> val; 
    }
  }
};
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  Bar<void, int> inst;
  inst.foo(1);
  return 0;
}
```

Error by MSVC:

> ```
> C:/msvc/v19_16/include\optional(87): error C2182: '_Value': illegal use of type 'void'
>
> C:/msvc/v19_16/include\optional(128): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Optional_destruct_base<_Ty,false>' being compiled
>   with
>   [
>        _Ty=void
>   ]
> ```

[Live demo](http://godbolt.org/z/kDtgXp)

Comment: Looks like an MSVC bug, since IRC the part under constexpr if shouldn't be instantiated if it depends on a template parameter, unless the branch was taken.

Comment: For what it's worth: the motivation of `if constexpr` was more or less exactly to make examples like that compile.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Definitively a bug of MSVC. A [bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/295561/discarded-if-constexpr-branch-incorrectly-causes-t.html) exist and has been reportedly fixed in Visual Studio 2019 Preview.

---

`if constexpr` is standardized in [`[stmt.if]/2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.if#2):

> If the `if` statement is of the form `if constexpr`, the value of the condition shall be a contextually converted constant expression of type bool; this form is called a constexpr if statement.

This applies.

> If the value of the converted condition is false, the first substatement is a *discarded statement*, otherwise [...].

It also applies, making in your program `{ std::optional<T> val; }` a *discarded statement*.

> During the instantiation of an enclosing templated entity (ndYSC `Bar<void, int>`), if the condition is not value-dependent after its instantiation, the discarded substatement (if any) **is not instantiated**.

Comment: I downloaded Visual Studio 2019 Preview and tried to compile the code with the compiler version 19.20 that shipped with it. The issue from the bug report which you mentioned is indeed solved ... but unfortunately my code snippet still does not compile (I get the same compiler errors as before).

Comment: I created a bug report:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/425475/msvc-compiler-v1920-preview-2019-and-versions-1916.html

Answer (score 5):

Along with @YSC's answer, also relevant is [`[temp.inst]/10`](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#10):

> An implementation shall not implicitly instantiate a function template, a variable template, a member template, a non-virtual member function, a member class, a static data member of a class template, or a substatement of a constexpr if statement , unless such instantiation is required.

Answer (score 1):

I could observe the issue is only partially fixed (VS 16.6.0 Preview 3.0 - cl Version 19.26.28803.1). Now you can observe the following: [GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/7j_U6c)

- It works in classes without template parameter packs.
- It works now correctly with in-class definitions but not with out-class definitions.

(the error occurs only in `/permissive-` mode which is enabled by default)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <optional>

#define IN_CLASS_DEF_FUNC 0
#define WITH_PARAM_PACK 1

//1, 1 -> works
//0, 1 -> error (invalid use of type void)
//0, 0 -> works
//1, 0 -> works

template<typename T
#if WITH_PARAM_PACK    
    , typename... Args
#endif
>
struct Bar
{

#if IN_CLASS_DEF_FUNC
    void foo()
    {
        if constexpr (!std::is_same_v<T, void>) // false
        {
            // MSVC compiler error occurs because of the line below; no error occurs when compiling with GCC and Clang 
            std::optional<T> val;
        }
    }
#else
    void foo();
#endif
};

#if !IN_CLASS_DEF_FUNC
template<typename T
#if WITH_PARAM_PACK    
    , typename... Args
#endif
>
void Bar<T
#if WITH_PARAM_PACK    
    , Args...
#endif
>::foo()
{
    if constexpr (!std::is_same_v<T, void>) // false
    {
        // MSVC compiler error occurs because of the line below; no error occurs when compiling with GCC and Clang 
        std::optional<T> val;
    }    
}
#endif

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Bar<void> inst;
    inst.foo();

    Bar<int> inst_okay;
    inst_okay.foo();

    return 0;
}
```

BTW: as a quickfix you can move your generic code in free standing function without a parameter pack...